# Как передать значение переменной php в html тег?

Tags: php, html

Хочу передать значение переменной $x из файла getdata.php в html тег файла data.php

При этом файл getdata.php находится в каталоге php, а файл data.php в корне сервера.

---

Пробовал делать таким образом:

Код файла getdata.php

```
<?php
    $x = 'Привет мир!';
    require_once('../data.php');
?>
```

Код файла data.php

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>Переменная из php:
    <span><?php echo $x; ?></span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ничего не выводится.

---

Пробовал делать таким образом:

Код файла getdata.php

```
<?php
  $x = 'Привет мир!';  
?>
```

Код файла data.php

```
<? include_once "php/getdata.php"; ?>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>Переменная из php:
   <span><?php echo $x; ?></span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ничего не выводится и возникает 
Warning: include_once(php/getdata.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\test\data.php on line 1

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'php/getdata.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/PEAR/pear') in W:\domains\test\data.php on line 1

---

Скажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `include_once "/php/getdata.php";` для начала последнее `.php` лишнее, а первый слэш нужен, чтобы обращаться к файлу из корня "сайта", но тут могу вас ввести в заблуждение, потому что я не теоретик, мог позабывать все давно

Comment: Все равно результат тот же (

Comment: `include_once __DIR__ . "/php/getdata.php";` или `chdir(__DIR__); include_once "php/getdata.php";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getdata.php

```
<?php
  $x = 'Привет мир!';  
?>
```

data.php

```
 <? require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/php/getdata.php"); ?>
    <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div>Переменная из php:
       <span><?php echo $x; ?></span>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Ошибка из-за слэша в адресе

Comment: Все равно результат тот же: Ничего не выводится и возникает Warning: include_once(/php/getdata.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\domains\test\data.php on line 1

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/php/getdata.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64;w:/modules/php/PHP-7.2-x64/PEAR/pear') in W:\domains\test\data.php on line 1

Comment: @КириллМиронов ошибка потому что интерпритатор не находи файла getdata.php, путь не правильный, вот так попробуй, как я переправил в ответе. Все заработает

Comment: Если файл находится в корне, то require_once('./data.php');